# The most "beautiful" function to select radio buttons by name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I still find a bit confusing actively selecting (setting) radio buttons in jQuery (a lot of different ways to achieve it)

I use this function `setRadioButton(radioName, option)` which allows me to select a radio button by name and option which I want to actively select

```js
function setRadioButton(radioName, option){
    
    var $radios = $('input[type="radio"][name="'+radioName+'"]');
    for (var i=0; i<$radios.length; i++){        
        if($radios[i].value == option) {
            $radios[i].checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

monthly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="monthly">
<br>
quarterly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="quarterly">
<br>
half yearly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="half_yearly">
<br>
yearly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="yearly">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="select monthly" onclick="setRadioButton('period','monthly')">
<input type="button" value="select quarterly" onclick="setRadioButton('period','quarterly')">
<input type="button" value="select half_yearly" onclick="setRadioButton('period','half_yearly')">
<input type="button" value="select yearly" onclick="setRadioButton('period','yearly')">
```

Is there any simpler built-in jQuery function?
Is this function ok? Which suggestions might you provide?

Comment: You could start with `$(':radio')` to save some characters which is shorthand for  `$('input[type="radio"]')` - see the [docs here](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop through all the radio inputs. You can use:

```
function setRadioButton(name, option){
   $('input[name="' + name + '"][value="'+option+'"]').click();
}
```

to select the specific radio by it's value and `click` it.

```js
function setRadioButton(name, option){
   $('input[name="' + name + '"][value="'+option+'"]').click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

monthly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="monthly">
<br>
quarterly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="quarterly">
<br>
half yearly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="half_yearly">
<br>
yearly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="yearly">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="select monthly" onclick="setRadioButton('period', 'monthly')">
<input type="button" value="select quarterly" onclick="setRadioButton('period', 'quarterly')">
<input type="button" value="select half_yearly" onclick="setRadioButton('period', 'half_yearly')">
<input type="button" value="select yearly" onclick="setRadioButton('period', 'yearly')">
```

Comment: The example above is using `$('input[name="period"][value="'+option+'"]')` which is filtering by `name="period"`.

Comment: your function doesn't seem to work quite perfectly, when you click several times in different buttons. Could you kindly also add to the function the parameter `radioName`?

Comment: thank you, perfect solution, because now when I call that function, it also triggers any event handler `onclick`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding `onclick` listeners on every `input` directly inside the DOM, I would suggest you to use `eventListeners` instead. Note that `jQuery` is not necessary.

```js
let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]');

Array.from(btns).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let option = v.getAttribute('data-attr');
  Array.from(checks).find(c => c.value == option).checked = true;
}));
```

```html
monthly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="monthly">
<br>
quarterly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="quarterly">
<br>
half yearly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="half_yearly">
<br>
yearly
<input type="radio" name="period" value="yearly">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="select monthly" data-attr='monthly'>
<input type="button" value="select quarterly" data-attr='quarterly'>
<input type="button" value="select half_yearly" data-attr='half_yearly'>
<input type="button" value="select yearly" data-attr='yearly'>
```

Comment: Thank you! But could you write as a function with `name` and `option` arguments as it is in the OP?